# Display an image using Glide in Android. Can't see anything

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-developer-api

I'm trying to display an image using Glide in my ImageView to no avail. I don't get any errors, but I don't see any image either

build.gradle dependencies:

```
 implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
 annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
```

my ImageView Layout:

```
       <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profilPicture"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/medicine">

       </ImageView>
```

In my MainActivity I try to display the image within a thread

```
       val thread = Thread {
        try {
            Glide.with(this)
                .load("http://via.placeholder.com/300.png")
                .into(profilPicture)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    thread.start()
```

Comment: Mention the log. And it might be that your image is loaded but due to background it is now visible clearly. Have you used `listener` to check either the resource is successfully loaded or not?

Comment: Why are you doing it using a thread though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to create separate `thread` for loading because `Glide` does it for you. Just:

```
Glide.with(this)
    .load("http://via.placeholder.com/300.png")
    .into(profilPicture)
```

Will be enough

Answer (score 2):

Glide not required thread.it work on ui thread async manner.also check your image size and internet connection.

```
Glide.with(this).load(url).into(view);
```